# Sorting strings based off of value of letters added together. (Java)

Tags: java, sorting

This is my first post here so please bear with me. I'm self-teaching myself Java in attempts to prepare for a Computer Science course.I'm planning on taking next year and I was given a problem.

The problem tasks me to assign values to lower case letters with `a = 1, b = 2...` to `z = 26`. Then I will have write a method which given an array of strings `String[] names` will sort them in terms of which array has the biggest value of letters added together. For example, "ed" would have the value 9 because e is 5 and d is 4.

Another example, given `annie, bonnie, liz` the method will sort to `bonnie, liz, annie`.

I'm kind of confused with how to approach this in terms of code and am looking for some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i am not going to solve the exact problem for you as you learn more by experimenting yourself... however you may take this inspiration

```
public class Sorting {
    public static Map<Character, Integer> characters = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    static{
        characters.put('a', 1);
        characters.put('b',2);
    }

    static class StringValue implements Comparable<StringValue> {
        private Integer value = 0;
        private String name = "";
        public StringValue(String name){
            this.name = name;
            for(char aChar : name.toCharArray()){
                value += Sorting.characters.get(aChar);
            }
        }
        public int compareTo(StringValue o) {
            return value.compareTo(o.value);
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        String [] values = {"bb", "a", "aa" , "abaa"};
        List<StringValue> stringVals = new ArrayList<StringValue>();
        for(String val : values){
            stringVals.add(new StringValue(val));
        }
        Collections.sort(stringVals);
        for(int i = 1; i <= stringVals.size(); i++){
            StringValue aVal = stringVals.get(i-1);
            System.out.println(aVal.getName() + " has value " + aVal.getValue() + " and rank " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
a has value 1 and rank 1
aa has value 2 and rank 2
bb has value 4 and rank 3
abaa has value 5 and rank 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code something like this.

```
public class J2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        J2 j = new J2();

        String s[] = {"annie", "bonnie", "liz"};
        j.sortArray(s);

    }

    void sortArray(String[] arr2) {
        int ww[] = new int[arr2.length];

        //find the integer value total of words and put in to array
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            String s = arr2[i];
            char[] c = s.toCharArray();
            int w = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                w += (int) c[j] - 96;
            }
            ww[i] = w;
        }

        // sort the array acordind to values
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length - 1; j++) {
                if (ww[j] < ww[j + 1]) {
                    int t = ww[j];
                    ww[j] = ww[j + 1];
                    ww[j + 1] = t;

                    String s = arr2[j];
                    arr2[j] = arr2[j + 1];
                    arr2[j + 1] = s;
                }
            }
        }

        //print the array 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr2[i]);
        }

    }

}
```